# List Lookup Column - Select Library

Tags: list, lookup-column, library

I would like to add a lookup column in a SP list, which allows the user to select a specific library (rather than an item within that library).

Is this possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a lookup for a "List name" in SharePoint.

Possible alternatives would be creating a choice column which has a list of values, or customizing the new item page (using JS link) to fetch a set of lists inside current web and display them in a drop-down.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good alternative as I just want to display the library name as a text field (i.e. do nothing further with it) as Ankit Kumar also suggests below.

Answer (score 0):

And then do what? Are you going to call that list items afterwards? Please elaborate your requirement.

If you just want the list/library names in a look up field you can create a separate SharePoint list with all List Library names in a column and then call it as a lookup value.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the following approach:

1. Create a list (let's call it the Master list) with a single Title column (or more if required).
2. Create an event receiver which would handle `ListAdded` event. Develop your event receiver so that every time a list (or a library) is added to the web site a corresponding item is added to the Master list - for example the name of the list/library.
3. Add a lookup column to your second list and configure it to get items from your Master list.

That way you will have a lookup (dropdown) column with the names of the lists on your site.